# Merge Points from a list if a condition is met

Tags: c#, linq

I have list which stores points from a triangle (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3).
Some of these triangles are stored like rectangles meaning some of their points are equal.
I need to iterate my list and merge the rows so they return a new list for rectangle points.

A rectangle is shaped when a triangle has exactly **two** points equal with another triangle.

I already tried grouping.

I need to have a new Four point Rectangle Object. with the four points from the triangles.
I am sure there are intersecting triangles in my list.

```
 [
  {
    "y1": 12812.2936,
    "y2": 17665.7353,
    "y3": 17665.7353,
    "x1": 15316.4846,
    "x2": 15316.4846,
    "x3": 20137.1603
  },
  {
    "y1": 12812.2936,
    "y2": 12812.2936,
    "y3": 17665.7353,
    "x1": 15316.4846,
    "x2": 20137.1603,
    "x3": 20137.1603
  },
  {
    "y1": 26151.1303,
    "y2": 12812.2936,
    "y3": 12812.2936,
    "x1": 853.6957,
    "x2": 853.6957,
    "x3": 9352.5527
  },
  {
    "y1": 26151.1303,
    "y2": 26151.1303,
    "y3": 24752.8575,
    "x1": 853.6957,
    "x2": 2241.3005,
    "x3": 2241.3005
  },
  {
    "y1": 26151.1303,
    "y2": 24752.8575,
    "y3": 12812.2936,
    "x1": 853.6957,
    "x2": 2241.3005,
    "x3": 9352.5527
  },
  {
    "y1": 24752.8575,
    "y2": 24752.8575,
    "y3": 12812.2936,
    "x1": 2241.3005,
    "x2": 9352.5527,
    "x3": 9352.5527
  },
  {
    "y1": 45117.4663,
    "y2": 45117.4663,
    "y3": 49080.3743,
    "x1": 1295.4000,
    "x2": 4089.4000,
    "x3": 4089.4000
  },
  {
    "y1": 45117.4663,
    "y2": 49080.3743,
    "y3": 49080.3743,
    "x1": 1295.4000,
    "x2": 1295.4000,
    "x3": 4089.4000
  },
  {
    "y1": 21158.2000,
    "y2": 28952.8000,
    "y3": 28952.8000,
    "x1": 12830.2000,
    "x2": 12830.2000,
    "x3": 15884.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 21158.2000,
    "y2": 21158.2000,
    "y3": 28952.8000,
    "x1": 12830.2000,
    "x2": 15884.5000,
    "x3": 15884.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 57012.5000,
    "y2": 57012.5000,
    "y3": 57774.5000,
    "x1": 15884.5000,
    "x2": 644.5000,
    "x3": 644.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 57012.5000,
    "y2": 57774.5000,
    "y3": 57774.5000,
    "x1": 15884.5000,
    "x2": 15884.5000,
    "x3": 644.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 90889.3000,
    "y2": 90889.3000,
    "y3": 102116.1000,
    "x1": 15884.5000,
    "x2": 12830.2000,
    "x3": 12830.2000
  },
  {
    "y1": 90889.3000,
    "y2": 102116.1000,
    "y3": 102116.1000,
    "x1": 15884.5000,
    "x2": 15884.5000,
    "x3": 12830.2000
  },
  {
    "y1": 96747.5000,
    "y2": 99206.7000,
    "y3": 99206.7000,
    "x1": 12830.2000,
    "x2": 12830.2000,
    "x3": 644.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 96747.5000,
    "y2": 96747.5000,
    "y3": 99206.7000,
    "x1": 12830.2000,
    "x2": 644.5000,
    "x3": 644.5000
  },
  {
    "y1": 76243.7000,
    "y2": 79679.1000,
    "y3": 79679.1000,
    "x1": 2689.2000,
    "x2": 2689.2000,
    "x3": 758.8000
  },
  {
    "y1": 76243.7000,
    "y2": 76243.7000,
    "y3": 79679.1000,
    "x1": 2689.2000,
    "x2": 758.8000,
    "x3": 758.8000
  }]
```

My results should be new Rectangle Object with (x1, y1) ... (x4, y4).
Two of these points should be the intersecting points of the given triangles.

What needs to be done.
Iterate over the list with one object. 
Find if a triangle matches two points.
IFF it has two matching point return a new object with merged triangles(as rectangles).

**Do not consider edge cases.**

If thinking of triangles is confusing. Think the problem like this.
if one object in the list has at list two points equal to another object in the list merge the two of them into a new object Rectangle with merged the two points and the two points remaining from the two triangles.

The solutions provided work. I would like to do this using purely linq.

Comment: Please provide sample dataset to illustrate your point, it's not clear what you mean by "Some of these triangles are stored like rectangles meaning some of their points are equal"

Comment: You need to show some example input data and expected results, as well as your attempt with clear statement of what is wrong with it.

Comment: A triangle only has 3 angles.  Where does the 4th angle(point) come from?

Comment: Here are your data. 
These are coordinates to a matrix. Each point should have 2 points equal with another point in order to consider these two points a rectangular.
@jdweng if you merge two triangles you have a square. No edge cases are required

Comment: The fact that two triangles share two points in common does not mean they form a **rectangle**.  They will form a **quadrilateral**, certainly, and sometimes might form a rectangle or even a square.  Do you need to check for the presence of an actual rectangle when a match is found?  Or do you need to change the name?

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes you are correct please do not consider such cases. You can take it for granted that they will form a rectangle.

Comment: Putting two triangle together you get a four sided figure which is sometimes a rectangle.

Comment: @jdweng yes you are right as i mentioned before such cases do not exist in my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
class Point
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Point other && x == other.x && y == other.y;

    public override int GetHashCode() => x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode();
}

class Triangle {
    public double x1 {get; set;}
    public double x2 {get; set;}
    public double x3 {get; set;}
    public double y1 {get; set;}
    public double y2 {get; set;}
    public double y3 {get; set;}    

    protected virtual IEnumerable<Point> Points => new []{
         new Point(x1, y1),
         new Point(x2, y2),
         new Point(x3, y3),
    };

    public Point HasTwoMatchingPoints(Triangle other){
        var notMatchingPoints = Points.Except(other.Points);

        return notMatchingPoints.Count() == 1
            ? notMatchingPoints.First() // it means another 2 points are identical
            : null;
    }
}

class Rectangle : Triangle
{
    public Rectangle(Triangle triangle, Point point)
    {
        x1 = triangle.x1;
        x2 = triangle.x2;
        x3 = triangle.x3;
        x4 = point.x;
        y1 = triangle.y1;
        y2 = triangle.y2;
        y3 = triangle.y3;
        y4 = point.y;
    }

    public double x4 { get; set; }
    public double y4 { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<Triangle>();
// populate your list of triangles somehow, e.g. using JsonConvert    
var result = new List<Rectangle>();

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++){
        var point = list[i].HasTwoMatchingPoints(list[j]);
        if(point != null) {
            // create a rectangle from the triangle and the 4th point
            var rect = new Rectangle(list[j], point);
            result.Add(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

**Working example with your data:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/u61s36

Comment: Won't your code match triangles with themselves? Also your second `for` tests `i` and not `j` and increments `i`, so you are just comparing each triangle to the second one.

Comment: You're right, of course there must be `j` in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code below loads in your your triangles and finds pair of triangles with a single shared side (the `joinTriangles` variable)

From these pairs of triangles you can build your rectangles (quadrilaterals).

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@".\Triangles.json");
var triangles = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Triangle>>(json).ToArray();

var joinedTriangles = new List<Tuple<Triangle, Triangle>>();

for (var i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = i + 1; j < triangles.Length; j++)
    {
        if (HaveSharedSide(triangles[i], triangles[j]))
        {
            joinedTriangles.Add(new Tuple<Triangle, Triangle>(triangles[i], triangles[j]));
        }
    }
}

private static bool HaveSharedSide(Triangle triangle1, Triangle triangle2)
{
    int numberOfMatchingPoints = 0;

    if (triangle1.x1 == triangle2.x1 && triangle1.y1 == triangle2.y1)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x1 == triangle2.x2 && triangle1.y1 == triangle2.y2)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x1 == triangle2.x3 && triangle1.y1 == triangle2.y3)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x2 == triangle2.x1 && triangle1.y2 == triangle2.y1)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x2 == triangle2.x2 && triangle1.y2 == triangle2.y2)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x2 == triangle2.x3 && triangle1.y2 == triangle2.y3)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x3 == triangle2.x1 && triangle1.y3 == triangle2.y1)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x3 == triangle2.x2 && triangle1.y3 == triangle2.y2)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    if (triangle1.x3 == triangle2.x3 && triangle1.y3 == triangle2.y3)
    {
        numberOfMatchingPoints++;
    }

    var haveSharedSide = numberOfMatchingPoints == 2;

    return haveSharedSide;
}
```